# Как отловить нажатие на отдельный элемент RecyclerView android?

Tags: android

Я уже много видел материала по данной тематике даже здесь, а именно нажатия на отдельные элементы списка. У меня приложение получает с сервера два списка сообщений, входящие и исходящие. И при нажатие на один из элементов двух этих списков нужно переходить на активити которое содержит выбранное сообщение. При нажатии нужно как-то вытащить id того сообщения на которое мы нажали и перекинуть это id в запрос. У меня на данный момент есть такой адаптер для RecyclerView:

```
public class MessageAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter2.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;

    private SharedPreferences tok_pref;
    private final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

    MessageAdapter2(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new MessageAdapter2.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.from.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
        holder.date.setText(message.getDate());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView from, subject, date;

        ViewHolder(final View v) {
            super(v);
            subject = v.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            from = v.findViewById(R.id.from);
            date = v.findViewById(R.id.date);


            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                            .client(client)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

                    tok_pref = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(ACCESS_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String access_token = tok_pref.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, "");

                    APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
                    mAPIService.messView("Bearer " + access_token, 2409277, 0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ViewMessage>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Response<ViewMessage> response) {

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });


                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

на данный момент я повесил на клик по элементу сообщения отправку запроса с id сообщения которое я ввел вручную, у меня есть функция getId в классе-ответе с сервера, то есть получить это id можно, но я не пойму как отловить нажатие на отдельный элемент списка. Я видел способы использования position но у меня они почему-то не прижились))

### UPDATE:

Мой проблемный кусок кода.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
        holder.tvDate.setText(message.getDate());

        holder.tvDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(keyMessageId, position);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvFrom = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvSubject = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvDate = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);


        }
    }
```

вероятнее всего где-то ошибка)) но вот допустим я передам на следующее активити position на который я нажал(тоже кстати так и не понял как). Дальше мне нужно получить id которое принадлежит тому position что бы вывести нужное мне письмо, так вот появился вопрос, нельзя-ли как-то передать сразу id на следующее активити что-бы его сразу вставлять в запрос?

Спасибо всем за ценные советы, ответы и критику)). Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Либо создайте отдельный метод в том классе, в который должны перейти и в методе `onBindViewHolder` вызывайте метод из класса и передавая туда `position` либо из того же `onBindViewHolder` реализуйте вызов класса (интент) с передачей текущей позиции в данном случае с передачей `position`.

Comment: Или просто весь ваш `v.setOnClickListener...` со всем содержимым перенесите в `onBindViewHolder` и перед `v` поставьте `holder` чтобы получилось `holder.v.setOnClickListener...` и там, куда нужно передать текущую позицию передавайте `poisiton`.

Comment: а можно как-то передавать не `position` а id которое относится к выбранному позишн?

Comment: Можно, вы ведь получаете этот `id`? Получайте и если будете использовать `intent` передавайте этот `id` через `intent.putExtra`, а потом в активити к которому переходите получайте его через `getIntExtra`.

Comment: да я получаю этот `id`, но есть маленькая проблемка - я пытаюсь использовать `intent` в `onBindViewHolder`, но почему-то у меня не принимается переход на другое активити. и я не очень понимаю как я смогу вытащить определенное `id` которое принадлежит определенной position?

Comment: 1. Добавьте код интента в вопрос. 2. Вы получаете все имеющиеся `id`, и передаете тот, который соответствует `position`. 3. Или вы делаете запрос к `id` по `position` извелкаете и передаете в активити `id` равный `position` - то есть к номеру текущего айтема в ресайкле.

Comment: я обновил вопрос, @McDaggen если можно объясните поподробнее 3 пункт вашего последнего комментария, так как хотелось-бы передавать в следующее активити сразу id.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81323/discussion-between-mcdaggen-and-andrew-goroshko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем классе `MessageShow` обявите статическую переменную типа `String` для получения `id` сообщения, которое вы будете передавать через адаптер `RecyclerView:

```
public static final String keyMessageId = "message_id";
```

Затем в вашем адаптере вызовите интент по клику на любой из пунктов вашего `RecyclerView`:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messageList.get(position);
    holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());
    holder.from.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
    holder.date.setText(message.getDate());

    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
            // Сюда в качестве ключа передаем обявленную в классе
            // MessageShow перменную keyMessageId
            // А в качестве содержимого передаем текущую позицию
            intent.putExtra(keyMessageId, position);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Затем в самом классе `MessageShow` получаем переменную `messageId`:

```
long numberMessageId = getIntent().getIntExtra(keyMessageId, 0);
```

В классе `MessageShow` создаем метод, например с именем `getContentInServer`, в этот метод ставим весь ваш код из `ViewHolder`:

```
private void getContentInServer(long idMessage) {
    // idMessage вставьте туда, где вы указали id вручную
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                tok_pref = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(ACCESS_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String access_token = tok_pref.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, "");

                APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
                mAPIService.messView("Bearer " + access_token, 2409277, 0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ViewMessage>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Response<ViewMessage> response) {

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }
}
```

И затем в методе `onCreate` вашего класса `MessageShow` вызываем метод `getContentInServer`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// В данный метод передаем переменную numberMessageId полученную в интенте
// Которую вы должны были указать там, где указывали id вручную.
getContentInServer(numberMessageId);
}
```

И совет, не указывайте имена переменных одним словом, у вас в `TextView` имя переменной `from`, система иначе может распознать такое имя у переменной. Лучше ставьте первые буквы из самих вью, например tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvFrom = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
        tvSubject = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
        tvDate = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня почему-то данная переменная предлагает cast к классу message long messageId = messageList.get(position); и  holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() здесь v подчеркивает красным, может где-то что-то не дописал?

Comment: Да, действительно, он предлагает передать модель вместо переменной long. Тогдай передайте вместо messageId просто position. Отредактировал

Comment: а как view реализовать в onBindViewHolder, так как переменная v не видится и требует инициализации?

Comment: Я же сделал там `holder.v.setOnClickListener`, то что вы объявили во `ViewHolder` в методе `onBindViewHolder` получаете через `holder.`, как тут у вас `holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());`

Comment: вот я пробую все как вы говорили и походу делаю что-то не так)) я не могу сделать слушатель `setOnClickListener` в `holder`, и еще вопрос можно ли передавать вместо string  - int

Comment: в вашем `ViewHolder` есть `v` в `onBindViewHolder` вы делаете `holder.v.setOnClickListener`. Вместо String Int можно передавать, но система все равно будет ругаться чтобы преобразовали, так как невозможно передавать переменную типа String в виде Int не преобразовав, джава является строго типизированным языком.

Comment: мне вообще нужно передавать int полюбому string можно не затрагивать, но вот все равно не видит переменную v, может я вопрос обновлю и добавлю свой код, может вы увидите мою ошибку?

Comment: Обновите, но вы должны читать свой код и стараться понять где какие переменные объявляются и где и как они используются.

Comment: та я уже его 100 раз перечитал)) я могу сделать клик на любую надпись в элементе списка, а вот то что в вашем ответе никак почему-то... сейчас обновлю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81325/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-mcdaggen).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант (сам ещё не использовал и не проверял).
в адаптере:

```
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return messageList.get(position).getId();
  }
```

---

при создании адаптера:

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

---

в `onClick`:

```
long messageId = ViewHolder.this.getItemId();
```

Comment: вот у меня вопрос возник, я вот в вопросе показал код адаптера, я так понял что там нужно вставлять getItemId? при создании адаптера я пробовал прописать setHasStableIds но у меня не принялось это в коде, пишет что должно быть boolean.

Comment: _я пробовал прописать setHasStableIds_ - стесняюсь спросить, а Вы чего туда сували, что оно _не принялось_ ? У меня в ответе разве китайскими иероглифами написано слово `true`? Что здесь не понятного - первый метод скопипастить  в класс адаптера; при создании адаптера вызвать у него метод `setHasStableIds(true)`; и при клике Вы сможете получить `id` сообщения методом холдера `getItemId()`. Там же в `onClick` положить его в интент и вызвать `startActivity`.